# Создание библиотеки классов которая содержит алгоритмы сортировки

Tags: java, алгоритм, сортировка, библиотеки

Суть задания состоит в том, что бы реализовать 4 метода сортировки алгоритмов в коде и сделать библиотеку классов из этими алгоритмами, которую можно будет импортировать и использовать в другой программе. Но ранее я еще не создавал библиотеки, поэтому не совсем знаю как это сделать правильно. Подскажите пожалуйста правильно ли реализованы алгоритмы и что, и как делать для создания библиотеки.

**Bubble sort**

```
package Alg;

public class Bubble {

    public static void bubble_srt(int array[]) {
        int n = array.length;
        int k;
        for (int m = n; m >= 0; m--) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
                k = i + 1;
                if (array[i] > array[k]) {
                    swapNumbers(i, k, array);
                }
            }
            printNumbers(array);
        }
    }

    private static void swapNumbers(int i, int j, int[] array) {

        int temp;
        temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }

    private static void printNumbers(int[] input) {

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(input[i] + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] input = { 4, 2, 9, 6, 23, 12, 34, 0, 1 };
        bubble_srt(input);

    }
}
```

**Insertion sort**

```
package Alg;

public class Insert {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] input = { 4, 2, 9, 6, 23, 12, 34, 0, 1 };
        insertionSort(input);
    }

    private static void printNumbers(int[] input) {
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(input[i] + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    public static void insertionSort(int array[]) {
        int n = array.length;
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
            int key = array[j];
            int i = j - 1;
            while ((i > -1) && (array[i] > key)) {
                array[i + 1] = array[i];
                i--;
            }
            array[i + 1] = key;
            printNumbers(array);
        }
    }
}
```

**Merge sort**

```
package Alg;

public class Merge {
    private int[] array;
    private int[] tempMergArr;
    private int length;

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        int[] inputArr = { 45, 23, 11, 89, 77, 98, 4, 28, 65, 43 };

        Merge mms = new Merge();
        mms.sort(inputArr);
        for (int i : inputArr) {
            System.out.print(i);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }

    public void sort(int inputArr[]) {
        this.array = inputArr;
        this.length = inputArr.length;
        this.tempMergArr = new int[length];
        doMergeSort(0, length - 1);
    }

    private void doMergeSort(int lowerIndex, int higherIndex) {
        if (lowerIndex < higherIndex) {
            int middle = lowerIndex + (higherIndex - lowerIndex) / 2;
            doMergeSort(lowerIndex, middle);
            doMergeSort(middle + 1, higherIndex);
            mergeParts(lowerIndex, middle, higherIndex);
        }
    }

    private void mergeParts(int lowerIndex, int middle, int higherIndex) {
        for (int i = lowerIndex; i <= higherIndex; i++) {
            tempMergArr[i] = array[i];
        }
        int i = lowerIndex;
        int j = middle + 1;
        int k = lowerIndex;
        while (i <= middle && j <= higherIndex) {
            if (tempMergArr[i] <= tempMergArr[j]) {
                array[k] = tempMergArr[i];
                i++;
            } else {
                array[k] = tempMergArr[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }
        while (i <= middle) {
            array[k] = tempMergArr[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }

    }
}
```

**Selection sort**

```
package Alg;

public class Selection {

    public static int[] doSelectionSort(int[] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            int index = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++)
                if (arr[j] < arr[index])
                    index = j;

            int smallerNumber = arr[index];
            arr[index] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = smallerNumber;
        }
        return arr;
    }

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        int[] arr1 = { 10, 34, 2, 56, 7, 67, 88, 42 };
        int[] arr2 = doSelectionSort(arr1);
        for (int i : arr2) {
            System.out.print(i);
            System.out.print(", ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `public static void main()` определенно в классах не нужен

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Неизвестно, что конкретно подразумевается под библиотекой классов (лучше это уточнить у преподавателя). Вполне можно было бы обойтись одним классом с набором статических методов, каждый из которых сортирует определённым алгоритмом. Но более «объектно-ориентированно» будет ввести интерфейс абстрактного алгоритма сортировки (что-то вроде [паттерна «стратегия»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29)) и реализовать его несколько раз:

```
public interface SortAlgorithm {
    public void sort(int[] data);
}

public class BubbleSort implements SortAlgorithm {
    public void sort(int[] data) {
        ...
    }
}

public class SelectionSort implements SortAlgorithm {
    public void sort(int[] data) {
        ...
    }
}
```

И так далее. Такие алгоритмы было бы удобнее использовать. Например, если какой-нибудь более сложный код использует в своей работе сортировку, он может принимать на вход объект `SortAlgorithm` и сортировать, не заботясь о том, какой конкретно алгоритм там работает:

```
public void performSomeComplexCalculation(SortAlgorithm algo) {
   ...
   algo.sort(data);
   ...
}
```

А пользователь уже мог бы передавать конкретный алгоритм.

В библиотеке, конечно, не нужны методы `main()`, а также не нужен никакой код, который выводит числа (методы `printNumbers()`). Ну и хорошо бы JavaDoc написать перед методами. Раз это библиотека, подразумевается, что пользоваться методами может и кто-то другой и хорошо бы, чтобы он знал, что методы делают.

Вспомогательные методы вы совершенно правильно объявили `private`, так и оставляйте в библиотеке.

Вообще создание по-настоящему взрослой открытой Java-библиотеки включает:

- Автоматическую сборку (Maven, Gradle и т. д.)
- Хорошее покрытие юнит-тестами
- Публикация проекта в системе контроля версий (GitHub, BitBucket и т. д.)
- Публикация в Maven Central
- Подключение к системе непрерывной интеграции (Jenkins, Travis и т. д.)
- Тюториалы, примеры, хорошая документация, внимательное отношение к пользователям

Comment: Если определять интерфейс алгоритма сортировки, неплохо бы иметь версию с кастомным компаратором. Ну и generic. Ну и (Java-specific) отдельные версии для числовых типов.

Comment: @VladD, была мысль сказать про это, но всё же тут учебное задание. Вероятно, это не предполагалось.

Comment: Я бы на месте студента сказал. Иногда надо учить и преподавателя :)

Comment: interface -> implements.

Comment: @YuraIvanov, спасибо, поправил