# Как сделать из своей программы api?

Tags: java, api

Посоветуйте. Есть простая программа на java которая сравнивает 2 числа. 
Надо написать api чтобы другие могли пользоваться этой программой в своем коде.
Я представляю это так - другой программист в своем коде вызывает мою функцию. Что мне надо сделать, чтобы это стало возможным? Это тестовое задание. Первые шаги в программировании. 
Для примера можно любую программу использовать, например задаем 2 числа и она возвращает большее число.

Comment: заинклюдить свою твою либу он должен

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно сделать публичным класс и метод (объявить с модификатором `public`) и выложить Вашу программу в виде библиотеки. Достаточно много вариантов сборки Java-библиотеки.

Так же, если Вы используете Maven, можно загрузить Ваш проект и установить его в локальный репозиторий, но это уже тема систем сборки.

---

Вот более развернутый ответ на Ваш вопрос - [ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/450451/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8).